# Problem with \mintinline{latex} and ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, minted

I'd like to use code highlighting for LaTeX in my sectional titles. In the titles themselves it works, but the it does not in the Table of Contents. Here a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{\mintinline{python}{print ``this''}}
\mintinline{python}{print ``this''}

\section{\mintinline{latex}{\documentclass[]{}}}
\mintinline{latex}{\documentclass[]{}}

\end{document}
```

and the corresponding output:

[image]

The complete error from the `.toc` file reads:

```
\GenericError { }{LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble}{See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.}{Your command was ignored.\MessageBreak Type I <command> <return> to replace it with another command,\MessageBreak or <return> to continue without it.
```

Any ideas how to allow `\mintedinline` in the ToC entries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have either to robustify the `\minline` command or to use `\protect` in the section command. However, this does not prevent breaking into parts concerning the `\GenericError` issue. You should use the optional argument of `\section` and use explicit `\protect` for such commands like `\documentclass`, otherwise `\mintinline` will print `\documentclass` directly to the `ToC`, resulting in two `documentclass` statements in the file.

However, I doubt the usefulness of having this text in section titles and ToC!

```
\documentclass [A4]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\robustify\mintinline

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{\protect\mintinline{python}{print ``this''}}
\mintinline{python}{print ``this''}

\section[\mintinline{latex}{\protect\documentclass[]{}}]{\mintinline{latex}{\documentclass[]{}}}
\mintinline{latex}{\documentclass[]{}}



\end{document}
```

[image]